# How to Get Selected Record from Loop in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, loops, laravel, foreach

According to the loop in the fertilizer I'm just showing the value of one of them! It must be equal to the amount of data ID code because I want it to update the Value Form I, how do I do?
And if there is another way to say thanks.
In principle I would like to use AJAX Edition

```
@foreach($category as $cat)
            <tr>
                <td id="destroy_"><a data-delete id="destroy" data-id="{{$cat->id}}" href="#"><span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
                <td id="update_"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></td>
                <td><a href="{{action('categoryController@show', [$cat->id])}}">{{$cat->category}}</a>
                </td>
                <th id="dataId" class="text-right">{{$cat->id}}</th>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```